# Shake animation (3d version)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, animation, shake

I want to use this animation on errors, like the one shown [here](https://medium.com/@michaelvillar/improve-the-payment-experience-with-animations-3d1b0a9b810e):

[image]

How to achieve that in wpf? I have feeling this should be a combination (composition?) of multiple transformations, but which ones and how exactly?

Here is a starter (mcve or call it "my attempt"), which is ugly and is not even close to what I want:

```
<Grid>
    <Border x:Name="border"
            Width="200"
            Height="200"
            BorderBrush="Black"
            BorderThickness="1"
            CornerRadius="4"
            Background="LightBlue"
            RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0">
        <Border.RenderTransform>
            <TransformGroup>
                <ScaleTransform />
                <SkewTransform />
                <RotateTransform />
                <TranslateTransform />
            </TransformGroup>
        </Border.RenderTransform>
        <Border.Effect>
            <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="20" />
        </Border.Effect>
        <Button VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                Margin="0,0,0,10"
                Padding="5"
                Content="Click">
            <Button.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click">
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard FillBehavior="Stop">
                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="border"
                                             Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.Children[1].(SkewTransform.AngleX)"
                                             To="5" Duration="0:0:0.1"/>
                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="border"
                                             Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.Children[1].(SkewTransform.AngleX)"
                                             To="-5"
                                             BeginTime="0:0:0.1"
                                             Duration="0:0:0.2" />
                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="border"
                                             Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.Children[1].(SkewTransform.AngleX)"
                                             To="5"
                                             BeginTime="0:0:0.3"
                                             Duration="0:0:0.2" />
                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="border"
                                             Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.Children[1].(SkewTransform.AngleX)"
                                             BeginTime="0:0:0.5"
                                             Duration="0:0:0.1" />
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger>
            </Button.Triggers>
        </Button>
    </Border>
</Grid>
```

There are many 2d shake posts around ([click](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9467815/1997232), [click](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17434877/1997232)), but I need animation which tells **"you are wrong"** and not the one which says "let's dance".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the animation you describe. I have used a `Viewport3D` with a `Viewport2DVisual3D` to host the controls.

[image: 3DShake]

You could use this to build you own reusable custom shake control.

It is not possible to replicate this exact animation using simple 2D `RenderTransforms`.

```
<Grid>
    <Viewport3D>
        <Viewport3D.Camera>
            <PerspectiveCamera Position="0, 0, 4"/>
        </Viewport3D.Camera>
        <Viewport2DVisual3D x:Name="DVisual3D">
            <Viewport2DVisual3D.Transform>
                <RotateTransform3D>
                    <RotateTransform3D.Rotation>
                        <AxisAngleRotation3D Angle="0" Axis="0, 1, 0" />
                    </RotateTransform3D.Rotation>
                </RotateTransform3D>
            </Viewport2DVisual3D.Transform>
            <Viewport2DVisual3D.Geometry>
                <MeshGeometry3D Positions="-1,1,0 -1,-1,0 1,-1,0 1,1,0"
                        TextureCoordinates="0,0 0,1 1,1 1,0" TriangleIndices="0 1 2 0 2 3"/>
            </Viewport2DVisual3D.Geometry>
            <Viewport2DVisual3D.Visual>
                <Border x:Name="border"
                        Width="200"
                        Height="200"
                        BorderBrush="Black"
                        BorderThickness="1"
                        CornerRadius="4"
                        Background="LightBlue">
                    <Border.Effect>
                        <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="20" />
                    </Border.Effect>
                    <Button VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                            Margin="0,0,0,10"
                            Padding="5"
                            Content="Click">
                        <Button.Triggers>
                            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click">
                                <BeginStoryboard>
                                    <Storyboard FillBehavior="Stop">
                                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="DVisual3D"
                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Transform.(RotateTransform3D.Rotation).(AxisAngleRotation3D.Angle)"
                                        To="10" Duration="0:0:0.07"/>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="DVisual3D"
                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Transform.(RotateTransform3D.Rotation).(AxisAngleRotation3D.Angle)"
                                        To="-10"
                                        BeginTime="0:0:0.07"
                                        Duration="0:0:0.14" />
                                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="DVisual3D"
                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Transform.(RotateTransform3D.Rotation).(AxisAngleRotation3D.Angle)"
                                        To="10"
                                        BeginTime="0:0:0.21"
                                        Duration="0:0:0.14" />
                                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="DVisual3D"


                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Transform.(RotateTransform3D.Rotation).(AxisAngleRotation3D.Angle)"
                                    BeginTime="0:0:0.35"
                                    Duration="0:0:0.07" />
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                        </EventTrigger>
                        </Button.Triggers>
                </Button>
            </Border>
        </Viewport2DVisual3D.Visual>
        <Viewport2DVisual3D.Material>
            <DiffuseMaterial Viewport2DVisual3D.IsVisualHostMaterial="True" Brush="White"/>
        </Viewport2DVisual3D.Material>
    </Viewport2DVisual3D>
    <ModelVisual3D>
        <ModelVisual3D.Content>
            <DirectionalLight Color="#FFFFFFFF" Direction="0,0,-1"/>
        </ModelVisual3D.Content>
    </ModelVisual3D>
</Viewport3D>
```

Comment: Looks great, thanks. I am not sure if that fits (have to check drawbacks of using `ViewPort3D`), but animation looks similar to wanted.

Answer (score 4):

So far the best effect can be achieved like this:

[image]

```
<Grid>
    <Border Width="200"
            Height="200"
            BorderBrush="Black"
            BorderThickness="1"
            CornerRadius="4"
            Background="LightBlue"
            RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0">
        <Border.RenderTransform>
            <RotateTransform x:Name="transform" />
        </Border.RenderTransform>
        <Border.Effect>
            <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="20" />
        </Border.Effect>
        <Button VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                Margin="0,0,0,10"
                Padding="5"
                Content="Click">
            <Button.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click">
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard FillBehavior="Stop">
                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="transform"
                                             Storyboard.TargetProperty="Angle"
                                             From="5"
                                             Duration="0:0:0.5">
                                <DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                                    <ElasticEase EasingMode="EaseOut"
                                                 Oscillations="2"
                                                 Springiness="1" />
                                </DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                            </DoubleAnimation>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger>
            </Button.Triggers>
        </Button>
    </Border>
</Grid>
```

This giving that immerse feeling "something is wrong". I am satisfied until a better answer appears.